# JAVA OkHttpClient authenticator dont work for me with Bitbucket API

Tags: java, rest, authentication, curl

If i use the **Authentication** example of **OkHttpClient** as described (https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes at the end of the page) I'm successful. But if i try this to authenticate for **Bitbucket API** (Version2, Cloud) i get:

```
java.io.IOException: Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=FORBIDDEN, url=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myuser/test/pullrequests}
```

i tried:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myuser/test/pullrequests")
.get()
.build();
```

If i use **Curl** instead it works! - Short Version:

```
    String command = "curl -u myuser:mypass -X GET https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myuser/test/pullrequests");
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - i got it - i have to add the auth credentials to every request:

```
final String login = "myuser";
final String password = "mypass";
String credential = Credentials.basic(login, password);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myuser/test/pullrequests")
.header("Authorization", credential)
.get()
.build();
```